# SQL3 error inconsistent data types while executing a method

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this DB for movie management in cinemas:
FILM (ID_FILM, TITLE, DIRECTOR_NAME, PRODUCTION-BUDGET, RELEASE-DATE)
SCREENING(ID_SCREEN, ID_FILM*, SCREEN_DATE, ROOM, City)
SEEN (ID_SEEN, SPECTATOR_NAME, ID_SCREEN*, TICKET-PRICE).

I need to complete the Film type with the MySpectators method returning the whole (without duplicates) of its spectators. This is what I wrote for the signature and the body of this method :

```
create type tset_spectator as table of varchar(100);
/
```

```
alter type tfilm add member function MySpectators return tset_spectator cascade;
```

```
create or replace type body tfilm as member function MySpectators return tset_spectator
is
spectatorsfilms tset_spectator;
Begin
select CAST(MULTISET(
        select deref(deref(value(p)).screening_seen)
        from film f, table(f.film_screening) p
        where f.ID_FILM=self.ID_FILM) as tset_spectator)
        into spectatorsfilms
from dual;
return spectatorsfilms;
end;
End;
/
```

I got this error that I couldn't fix:
**PL / SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent data types; expected: REF; obtained: DBACINEMA.TSET_REF_SEEN**

*N.B I already created types, tables and nested tables before.*

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show us a DDL description of `DBACINEMA.TSET_REF_SEEN`? Looks like that is not `REF` but `deref()` expects `REF`

Comment: create type tset_ref_seen as table of ref tseen;
/

Comment: create or replace type tseen as object (ID_SEEN integer, SPECTATOR_NAME varchar(100), TICKET_PRICE integer, seen_screening Ref tscreening);
/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't showed your `DBACINEMA.TSET_REF_SEEN`, so I can only guess that is a collection and you need to use one more `table()`:

```sql
create or replace type body tfilm as member function MySpectators return tset_spectator
is
spectatorsfilms tset_spectator;
Begin
select CAST(MULTISET(
        select deref(value(scr_seen))
        from film f, table(f.film_screening) p
            ,table(deref(value(p)).screening_seen) scr_seen
        where f.ID_FILM=self.ID_FILM
        ) as tset_spectator)
        into spectatorsfilms
from dual;
return spectatorsfilms;
end;
End;
/
```

Comment: create type tset_ref_seen as table of ref tseen; /

Comment: create or replace type tseen as object (ID_SEEN integer, SPECTATOR_NAME varchar(100), TICKET_PRICE integer, seen_screening Ref tscreening); /

Comment: I didn't have errors, thank you, just one question do you advice me to write `select deref(value(scr_seen))` or `select value(scr_seen).SPECTATOR_NAME` or `select deref(value(scr_seen)).SPECTATOR_NAME` ?

Comment: @Byomi last one, just to make it more clear without implicit conversions